# Select rows from sheet1 & display in sheet2

Tags: excel, search, select, filter, extract

In Row1 on sheet1 I insert `ID`, `Description`, `Amount`

ID will have values such as:

```
01
02
03
01
02
04
01
```

On a separate sheet I would like to show only the rows which have `ID` `01`.
I would like this automatic, without using filter, or VBA

Is there any particular equation?

Comment: I assume your question is about Excel, right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe dLookup should do the trick